# getting this error nosuchelementexception : this element is locating but still idk why it is showing this exception.also help me with other exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation-testing, selenium-java

1.)Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

2.)org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Attempting to close incomplete json stream
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'

3.)Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

4.)Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[placeholder='Select Country']"}

**Note:does not allowing me to paste all code so just written down exception can anyone help me with these**

Comment: Please share all your code, if possibly including the link to the page you are working on

Comment: We want the code, UI (atleast parts of DOM), logs to better understand the problem . You may keep logs in Github gist and share it with us.